# Classes and subclasses - sending data from derived class to primary class

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to send data (fishname) from the class "Fish" to the primary class "Animal". I made an object, and tried to access the subclass function to send the data from the subclass to the primary class.

My goal: Send whatever I write in the readFish() to Animal 's private name char.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int STRLEN = 32;

class Animal {
private:
    char name[STRLEN];

public:
    Animal() { }                                     
    Animal(char animalname) { name[STRLEN] = animalname; }  
};



class AnimalInWater : public Animal {
private:

public:
    AnimalInWater() { }

};

class Fish : public AnimalInWater {
private:
    char fishname[STRLEN];   

public:
    void readFish() {
        cout << "The name of the fish: "; cin.getline(fishname, STRLEN);
        Animal(fishname);       // Is supposed to use the constructor seen in Animal class
    }

};

int main() {

    Animal a1;          
    d1.readFish();      // readFish() is in the Fish class, which is under AnimalInWater which is under Animal.
                        // In other words; the readFish() function is the granddaughter class of Animal.


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is homework... please tag as such.

Comment: `name[STRLEN] = animalname` doesn't do what you think it does. (Especially considering `animalname` is a plain `char`.

Comment: Tried tagging it as homework, but it said I didn't have enough reputation for that. Don't really get what you mean by that Arnav? The STRLEN part is supposed to set the length, doesn't it do that?

Comment: I retract my prior comment, sorry... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: Get in the habit of using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays and many defects will go away.  You can always use them when you *need* fixed length of characters (such as message passing or when records are fixed lengths).

Comment: What Arnav means is that `char animalname` is a single char. And that while `char name[STRLEN]` declares an array, `name[STRLEN] =...` sets one single character, the one in STRLEN position, which by the way is one past the end of the array, so it will led to undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm aware of char not being "the best" for strings, however due to the course I am taking I'm forced to use char for now. So Jorge, how would I fix that? Adding animalname[STRLEN] would fix that, or?

Comment: If you are forced to use chars, then I think you could change the Animal constructor to have a `char* animalname` as parameter and then use `strcpy` function or similar to copy the parameter content into `name`.

Answer (score 0):

> I made an object, and tried to access the subclass function to send the data from the subclass to the primary class.

You're talking about classes as though they were objects. If you have an instance of `Fish`, then it **is an** instance of `AnimalInWater` and also of `Animal` at the same time.

If you want `readFish()` to assign some value to `name`, then just assign it to `name` in that method in the `Fish` class.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, piece by piece.

The variable `name` is an array of `char` and has `STRLEN` slots.
The slots are numbered from 0 to `STRLEN`-1.

The expression `name[0]` represents the first slot.
The expression `name[STRLEN]` represents one past the end of the array.

The variable `animalname` is a *single* character.
The constructor is placing the value inside `animalname` to the slot `name[STRLEN]`, which is beyond the array.